# JPanel doesn't repaint if repaint() is called within JFrame code

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I have a class `Forest` and `CellularJPanel`, which extends `JPanel` and displays `Forest`. I wrote a primitive code to create `JFrame`, `Forest`, `CellularJPanel` and add `CellularJPanel` to the `JFrame`. Next is an infinite loop, which makes `Forest` update and `CellularJPanel` repaint.

```
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();          

    Forest forest = new Forest();
    CellularJPanel forestJPanel = new CellularJPanel(forest);

    jFrame.add(forestJPanel);

    jFrame.pack();
    //jFrame.setResizable(false);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            forestJPanel.repaint();
            forest.update();
            forest.sleep(); // calls Thread.sleep(...)
        }   
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Here is a code of the `CellularJPanel` class:

```
public class CellularJPanel extends JPanel
{
    private CellularAutomata cellularAutomata;

    public CellularJPanel(CellularAutomata cellularAutomata)
    {
        super();
        this.cellularAutomata = cellularAutomata;
        setPreferredSize(this.cellularAutomata.getDimension());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)     
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);            
        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        cellularAutomata.draw(graphics2D);
    }
}
```

If I use above code within `main()` method, then everything works fine, 
`CellularJPanel` repaints, `paintComponent()` is called normally.

If I paste the same code to UI JFrame button click event method, then new JFrame shows and even displays initial state of the `Forest`, because `paintComponent` is once called, when `jFrame.setVisible(true)` is called. Then **`while` loop is being executed, but `CellularJPanel` doesn't repaint, `paintComponent` is not called**. I have no idea why, maybe I should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` or `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` somehow, but I've tried them and it didn't work, I'm doing something wrong.

Any suggestions?

P.S.
My target is to display `CellularJPanel` within the same UI JFrame, from which button was clicked. But even if I add this panel to main UI JFrame, it doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank You :) StackOverflow is incredible usefull!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is having a `while(true)` on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which will block anything related to UI because UI events aren't getting handled anymore.

The event dispatch thread (a single thread) works down a queue of UI event messages, until it handles the one where your `while(true)` loop is running. It then blocks any further processing because there's an infinite loop on it. Calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` from that loop won't help because it posts an event to the event dispatch thread, which is blocked in the `while(true)` loop.

So remove that loop, instead use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to time your events. In the timer event, change the state of your UI and call for a `repaint`. The timer event will be synchronized with the UI thread, so changing state of UI components is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

There is a single UI thread that draws things - it's also the one that handles button clicks. In swing, this is called the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). If The UI thread is busy running a `while` loop, it can't paint.

You can quickly verify this by making your button click handler run only a single iteration of your loop (without the sleep): `forest.update(); forestJpanel.repaint();`

You can auto update from a separate thread (like `Timer`) that calls repaint/sleep in a loop.

Comment: Your answer also could be accepted, but TT had answered 2 minutes earlier :)

Comment: Technically the timestamps show mine was first by 2 mins, but oh well