# Thread.sleep not working

Tags: java, thread-sleep

so  im making a basic monopoly game. working on movement right now. Im trying to make it look like its actually moving, so i have it pausing for .5 seconds and then moving a square till it moves the amount of squares needed. For some reason whats happening is its freezing for .5 seconds * number of squares needed to move, and then moving to the final square. Any possible fixes?

```
    square[p1location].setBackground(c1);
    p1location+=moverate;
    square[p1location].setBackground(c2);
    try {
      validate();
      repaint();
      Thread.sleep(500);

   } catch (Exception c) {
      System.out.println(c);
   }
    move++;
    }
    move=0;

  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing some of the code. A [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example would be good.

Comment: Put in debug and check if your Thread.sleep code is executing.

Comment: add complete code

Comment: [Use a `javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule your UI updates and repaints every 500 ms. The way you are doing it now, you are blocking the EDT with sleeps. [Example of a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35382456/243373), explanation in the answers in that thread.

Answer (score -1):

Put Thread.sleep(500); before validate() and try.

Answer (score -1):

Sir, use the Thread.sleep() in loop then see the magic!

```
package com.usman;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(i);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }
  }
}
```